# How to fetch two different column values from two different tables inturn one value table is dependent on other table value

Tags: mysql

The following query is the one I was using previously... but I want to combine these two queries in order to improve the performance

```
select a, b, c
  from table1
 where d LIKE 'xxx'
   and f like 'yyyy'
 order by b desc;
```

I'm executing the above query and reading values.

For every value of b from above query again executing the below query in a loop.

```
select count(*) 
  from table2 where b=? AND js_email_id IN 
(
  select js_email_id 
    from js_initialsignup 
   where UCase(jsaccountstatus) LIKE UCase('live') 
     AND UCase(js_status) LIKEUCase('accepted')
)
```

How can I combine both queries and get count and values at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a,b,c,
       (select count(*) 
from table2 where b=a.b AND js_email_id IN 
(
  select js_email_id 
  from js_initialsignup 
  where UCase(jsaccountstatus) LIKE UCase('live') 
    AND UCase(js_status) LIKEUCase('accepted')
)) as cnt

from table1 a
```

Comment: is it possible to get ROW_NUMBERS() from above query in mysql

Comment: No its not there but you have alternates for that

Comment: but how is that related to this query?

Comment: from over all records i need to get only limited records every time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, COUNT(t2.*) 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.b = t2.b
INNER JOIN js_initialsignup j ON t2.js_email_id  = j.js_email_id 
WHERE t1.d LIKE 'xxx' 
  AND t1.f like 'yyyy'
  AND UCase(j.jsaccountstatus) LIKE UCase('live') 
  AND UCase(j.js_status) LIKE UCase('accepted'))" 
GROUP BY t1.a, t1.b, t1.c
ORDER BY by t1.b DESC;
```